# three.js transparent object occlusion

Tags: javascript, three.js

In a three.js scene, I would like to have an object that's not visible, but still occludes other objects in the scene as if it was visible.

Is this possible with the three.js library? Here is an example:

Suppose I have a three.js scene that contains 3 objects: object a, object b and object c and a camera. I would like object c to be invisible to the camera, but still occlude object b... Scenario 1:
[image: scenario 1 overview]
In scenario 1, here is what I would like the camera to see:
[image: scenario 1 camera view]

Scenario 2:
[image]
In scenario 2, here is what I would like the camera to see:
[image]

Can anyone tell suggest a technique use to achieve such an effect?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, in three.js you can create an object that is invisible, but still occludes other objects as if it were visible.

To do that, you need to use two features available in three.js: `Object3D.renderOrder` and `Material.colorWrite`.

You need to make sure the invisible object is rendered prior to the object(s) it must occlude.

You control the rendering order with the `renderOrder` property.

You make the occluding object invisible by setting its material's `colorWrite` property to `false`.

```
// material
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial();

// mesh a
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10, 4, 4 );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material.clone() );
mesh.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
mesh.renderOrder = 0; // <===================
mesh.position.z = - 10;
scene.add( mesh );

// mesh b
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material.clone() );
mesh.material.color.set( 0x606060 );
mesh.renderOrder = 3;
mesh.position.z = 0;
scene.add( mesh );

// mesh c
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 3, 3, 3 );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material.clone() );
mesh.material.color.set( 0x0000ff );
mesh.material.colorWrite = false; // <=================
mesh.renderOrder = 2;
mesh.position.z = 10;
scene.add( mesh );
```

three.js r.143

Comment: This is great!  I had just posted a more complicated answer (basically, how to modify the webGLrenderer to support something like this) to another similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28907508/occlusion-of-real-world-objects-using-three-js) which I've now updated to point here.  Looking forward to R71 coming out.