# three.js properties for occlusion in a-frame

Tags: aframe

I found this interesting info about object occlusion using mesh.renderorder and material.colorwrite.

[three.js transparent object occlusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion)

I couldn't find a way to set these directly with a-frame or the inspector. Is there a way?

Yes, I know how to set them directly with javascript. Doing this declaratively would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no declarative way built into A-Frame: the only properties provided by the `material` component are [documented here](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/material.html), and do not include `colorWrite`.

Since you already know how to set them declaratively with JavaScript (per the answer in the linked question), you could certainly [write an A-Frame component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html) creating a declarative syntax for what you want to do, and reuse that as needed.

Answer (score 1):

other than colorWrite, it MUST need renderOrder for the hidden object and the hider object.

[three.js transparent object occlusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion)