# Three.js see through object behind

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, textures

I have cube A (bigger) and cube B and they are colliding. Cube A have bigger width and height (X,Y), but cube B is bigger on axes Z (so cube B is going through cube A like a tunnel).

How can I set texture or something to cube B, to achieve my goal and it is see through object B with my camera and see what is behind A. (some transparency or something)

I hope you will be understand my question and there will be something :)

Comment: You will need to calculate vertices to model a hole(tunnel) in cube A. Some like a `Cut extrude`. You'll need some math to calculate the intersections.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion