# I want transparent texture in 'three.js'. but i want it to mask the object behind it

Tags: three.js

I want transparent texture in 'three.js'. but i want it to mask the object behind it.

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyAhl.png)

```
geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100);

// blue =====
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0x0000FF,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

bluePlane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
bluePlane.position.set(0, 0, 0);
scene.add(bluePlane);

// red =====
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFF0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});

redPlane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
redPlane.position.set(-50, 50, 1);
scene.add(redPlane);
```

I found a one solution. but this is like a hack or bug.

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w03KS.png)

```
// red =====
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xFF0000,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide,
    map: new THREE.Texture()
});
```

Which is the official way? and my solution really hack?

Comment: I think that's fine. :) As long as its not throwing warnings or errors...

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion

Comment: Thanks for answer.