# three js object masking / portal effect

Tags: three.js

In three.js I want to create a portal effect - where looking through the portal would mask some objects and not others. 
For example, you look through the portal and you could see a different world.

I'm new to three.js, and i've experimented with alphaMap and clippingPlanes but i  think my approach is incorrect.

This example below shows what i have on the left with the desired effect on the right.

[image: portal image demo]

This is a good example - https://www.magicleap.com/

Thank you for your direction

Comment: This PR might be interesting for you: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/12033

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion/28869802#28869802

Comment: @WestLangley - you are a **HERO**. This is exactly what i was after, thank you.