# Is is possible in Babylon.js to occlude an object using a transparent object

Tags: babylonjs, webxr

I am developing an AR application using Babylon.js. I need to hide a virtual object behind a real object using a transparent mesh, like is described on this question regarding Three.js: [three.js transparent object occlusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28869268/three-js-transparent-object-occlusion)

Is it possible to do something like this with Babylon.js, I haven't been able to figure it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use a mesh to occlude parts of another mesh, you only have to turn off and turn on the mesh (occluder) before and after rendering.

```
occluderMesh.onBeforeRenderObservable.add(() => engine.setColorWrite(false));
occluderMesh.onAfterRenderObservable.add(() => engine.setColorWrite(true));
```

Check this example: https://playground.babylonjs.com/#AAM6LK